# Given a comma separated string of hostnames in a variable, how I can make a dictionary of hostname and corresponding IP addresses as key value pairs

Tags: ansible, key-value

for example:

the variable host_name contains "host1, host2, host3, host4" as a string.

Now in ansible how do I:

1. Find corresponding IP addresses for each host.
2. Create key:value pairs of "hostname:IP address".
3. Loop through each key:value pair to run some operation on them.

Comment: Are you looking for [community.general.dig – query DNS using the dnspython library](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dig_lookup.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controller machine has sufficient access to your remote hosts.
In the example below I create two different host variables. `local_dict` which is only available on `localhost` (`host_vars['localhost']`), and in the second play I create a dictionary specific for that host only containing their hostname and ip.

In the first play  the `setup` module is delegated to my hosts from the `host_names` variable (assuming your inventory contains the same host names as in the variable). We save the result from the `setup` module using `register: result`.
`local_dict` is being created from the result of the using the module `set_fact` which will create a host variable for the current running host, in this case `localhost`/my `controller` host. Meaning I can only get this variable using the host_vars of the localhost: `host_vars['localhost']['local_dict']`.

As mentioned above the second play creates a dictionary on each host only containing the IP address and hostname of the current host, but from your question above it seems it's desired to use something like `local_dict`.

```yaml
# First play
---                                                                             
- hosts: localhost                                                              
  connection: local                                                             
  gather_facts: false                                                           
  vars:                                                                         
    host_names: "host1,host2"                                                   
  tasks:                                                                        
                                                                                
    - name: Gather facts from hosts in host_names variable                      
      setup:                                                                    
      remote_user: ansible                                                      
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"                                                 
      register: result                                                          
      with_items: "{{ host_names.split(',') }}"                                 
                                                                                
    - name: Localhost creates a dictionary containing information of all hosts
      set_fact:                                                                 
        local_dict: "{{ local_dict|default({}) | combine({item.item : item.ansible_facts.ansible_default_ipv4.address}) }}"
      with_items: "{{ result.results }}"                                        
                                                                                
    - debug:                                                                    
        msg: "Final result {{ local_dict }}"                                    
                                                                                
                                                                                
    - debug:                                                                    
        msg: "Key: {{ item.key }} Value: {{ item.value }}"                      
      with_dict: "{{ local_dict }}"                                             
            
# Second play                                                                    
- hosts: host1,host2                                                            
  remote_user: ansible                                                          
  tasks:                                                                        
    - debug:                                                                    
        msg: "{{ item.key }}"                                                   
      when: item.key == inventory_hostname                                      
      with_dict: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['local_dict']}}"                     
                                                                                
                                                                                
    - name: Every host creates their own remote_dict variable                   
      set_fact:                                                                 
        remote_dict: "{{ remote_dict|default({}) | combine({inventory_hostname : ansible_default_ipv4.address}) }}"
                                                                                
    - debug:                                                                    
        msg: "{{ remote_dict }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gather facts from hosts in host_names variable] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost -> host1] => (item=host1)
ok: [localhost -> host2] => (item=host2)

TASK [containgi all informatino] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>  ...
ok: [localhost] =>  ...
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Final result {'host1': '192.168.1.101', 'host2': '192.168.1.102'}"
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'host1', 'value': '192.168.1.101'}) => {
    "msg": "Key: host1 Value: 192.168.1.101"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'host2', 'value': '192.168.1.102'}) => {
    "msg": "Key: host2 Value: 192.168.1.102"
}

PLAY [host1,host2] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host2]
ok: [host1]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item={'key': 'host1', 'value': '192.168.1.101'}) => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
skipping: [host1] => (item={'key': 'host2', 'value': '192.168.1.102'}) 
skipping: [host2] => (item={'key': 'host1', 'value': '192.168.1.101'}) 
ok: [host2] => (item={'key': 'host2', 'value': '192.168.1.102'}) => {
    "msg": "host2"
}

TASK [Every host creates their own remote_dict variable] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]
ok: [host2]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": {
        "host1": "192.168.1.101"
    }
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": {
        "host2": "192.168.1.102"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```